# How dedicated do I have to be to flying to get my privates rating

Tags: flight-training

I am a new student pilot. I have flown for 3 lessons and my flight instructor asked me what path I want to take with flying.

Comment: What path _do_ you want to take? You doing this for fun, or future job opportunities?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean in terms of learning, or future aviating?

I was always clear and open with my school that PPL was the target for me, with no interest to ever go commercial etc. There are plenty of PPLers who fly for nothing more than pleasure, and plenty who couldn't get a Class 1 medical.

If you mean dedication to learning - well, you aren't going to get a licence by accident but I didn't find the PPL path particularly onerous.